# Two native libraries has different cpu architecture set

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries, cpu-architecture, abi

In my project I had one native shared library for `armeabi, mips, x86` and it worked fine on all devices (e.g. lib1.so). Now I added different native library and it has set of libraries for all of the architectures (`armeabi, armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, mips, x86, x86_64`). E.g. lib2.so. 
 And it giving me `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` on some of devices. For example it's trying to load from `armeabi-v7a` but there isn't lib1.so for this cpu architecture.
*How can I make it load differently for different libraries? Or maybe I can copy first lib1.so file to different architectures. But which folder should I copy to other folders?*

Comment: I also face the same issue recently with zoom sdk and this help me

Comment: AFAIK what you're trying to do isn't possible. Consider what would happen on a 64-bit device when you've got an arm64-v8a version of lib2 but only a 32-bit version of lib1. You need to provide the same set of variants for all your libraries. IIRC the installer will scan your APK to see if it contains any libraries for the device's primary ABI, and if so it installs all libraries that you've provided for that ABI (but not for any other ABIs). If your APK contains no libraries at all for the primary ABI, the installer tries the same thing for the device's secondary ABI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to add following to app gradle file

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi" , "mips", "x86 "
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, but only for half. It just load `armeabi , mips, x86` into apk and ignore other architectures. But for fast decision - yes, it works. Thanks! But I wondering if there is other way to load all the native libraries into apk.

Comment: In my case I was using zoom sdk, and in their documents they have mentioned that if I have to ignore what library haven't included.

Comment: It seems like there isn't other way to do this.

Comment: to add all of the ABIs, just list them all there, it will for sure work; I am not sure whether I could just put 'all' instead of listing them all there though [ndk-build could take that 'all' thing]. Once you get into the abiFilters, all necessary shared libs for the ABIs will be pulled into apk. Maybe you could elaborate on " But I wondering if there is other way to load all the native libraries into apk"?  give it a try to put: abiFilters 'all' and tell us how it goes [ I got no clue what the result will be :-) ]